# How do I receive value in website from android phone

Tags: android, web

I am sending the value from android phone to a website. The website is registered online through some free sources.

The code is,

```
public class HttpStorage extends AsyncTask{
   protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
   }

public void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new      
    HttpPost("http://pavithrakrishnakumar.simplesite.com/");

    try {
        List <NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken1", "username"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken2", "password"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        postData();
    return null;
}
}
```

Now I am not getting any error in android side. How do I retrieve the value in the above mentioned site

Comment: Use e.prinstacktrace(); to find if there is any error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new      
    HttpPost("http://pavithrakrishnakumar.simplesite.com/");

    try {
         List <NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken1", "username"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken2", "password"));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if(response != null) {

          int statuscode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if(statuscode==HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

          }
       }

 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 }
 }
```

Comment: After execute  service return HttpResponse and convert response as string after that you can parse it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $IDToken1 = $_POST['IDToken1'];
    $IDToken2 = $_POST['IDToken2'];
```

This is how u can retrieve the data from a post request in that script..

Comment: But how do i write this in that site or where i will write it. I am sorry to ask silly question. since i am new to this, i am asking you this question. Can you please help me. thanks

Comment: just create a php file in the server and to the address of the file post your request. "http://pavithrakrishnakumar.simplesite.com/" how u can send it to this?do u have any script over there?

Comment: and what response you are getting if it Http://200 OK means the post request sent correctly.

Comment: No i dont have any script in the site. I have no idea as how to  proceed?

Comment: if you have your script over there means you can get the data

Comment: please delete that comment i have taken that

Comment: sorry you should have a php script.. you can't code for a php script in that site right?can u get it?